# Change multiple values in Pandas Python in a flexible way

Tags: python, pandas, database

I have two dataframe (namely A and B) in pandas python that differ each other, but they have two common columns
'Date' 'Hour'.
I would like to bring values within a column from B to A based on common Date and Hour.
For instance,

A Dataframe

```
Date  Hour Color Number
10-5  1     B     3
10-6  2     A     3
11-3  10    B     3
12-4  9     A     3
```

B Dataframe

```
Date Hour Basic polygon
10-5 1     1     R
10-6 2     2     T
12-4 9     A     3T
```

and I would like to obtain:

```
Date  Hour Color Number polygon
10-5  1     B     3       R
10-6  2     A     3       T
11-3  10    B     3       nan
12-4  9     A     3      3T
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try `merge` left on Date and Hour:

```
import pandas as pd

dfa = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': {0: '10-5', 1: '10-6', 2: '11-3', 3: '12-4'},
    'Hour': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 10, 3: 9},
    'Color': {0: 'B', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'A'},
    'Number': {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 3}
})

dfb = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': {0: '10-5', 1: '10-6', 2: '12-4'},
    'Hour': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 9},
    'Basic': {0: '1', 1: '2', 2: 'A'},
    'polygon': {0: 'R', 1: 'T', 2: '3T'}
})

new_df = dfa.merge(dfb.drop(columns='Basic'), on=['Date', 'Hour'], how='left')

print(new_df)
```

`new_df`:

```
   Date  Hour Color  Number polygon
0  10-5     1     B       3       R
1  10-6     2     A       3       T
2  11-3    10     B       3     NaN
3  12-4     9     A       3      3T
```